# Closure Compiler does not apply @const on this

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to get this piece of code working:

```
/** @constructor */
function Foo()
{
    /** @const */
    this.bar = 5;

    // edit: does now work
    // this.bar = 3;
}

var f = new Foo();

// should be inlined (like other constants)
alert(f.bar);
```

I have already tried adding more annotations (types, constructor), `@enum` instead of `@const` (for `this.bar`), `me = this` all of which did not have any effect.

The [help page](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) was not really helpful on this.

Is there some way to get this working ? 
If not, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't have any general "inline properties" logic.  You can get this to inline in ADVANCED mode by using a prototype function:

```
/** @constructor */
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = function() { return 5 };

var f = new Foo();
alert(f.bar());
```

will compile to:

```
alert(5);
```

The compiler will do this if there is only a single definition of a method "bar" and "bar" is only ever used in a call expression.  The logic used for this isn't correct in the general case (if the call is on a object that doesn't define "bar" the call would throw). It is, however, considered "safe enough".

Comment: When prefixed with the `@const` annotation, a variable will be inlined (known as  [constant propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_propagation)) by the Closure Compiler, which works well for normal `var` statesments. That's the behaviour I am trying to reproduce with properties. It does have anything to do with the process you described.

Comment: As I said, the compiler has no support for this.  It will check @const annotations on class properties when it can but it is more conservative about actually using that information when performing optimization.

Comment: I played around with the compiler a bit more, but figured that you're right; there does not seem to be a way to do this. Anyway, I am using cpp now.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `/** @constructor */` works:

```
/** @constructor */
function Foo()
{
    /** @const */ 
    this.bar = 5;

    // cc does not complain
    //this.bar = 3;
}

var f = new Foo();

// should be inlined
alert(f.bar);
```

compiles to:

```
alert((new function() { this.a = 5 }).a);
```

if i uncomment the `this.bar = 3;` i get this expected warning:

```
JSC_CONSTANT_PROPERTY_REASSIGNED_VALUE: constant property bar assigned a value more than once at line 9 character 0
this.bar = 3;
^
```

Comment: It still does not inline `f.bar` in the same way as other constants. This should output `alert(5)`.

Comment: Well, that sounds like bad news, +1 for your help anyway. Still looking for a hack to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation is said that:

The compiler produces a warning if a variable marked with @const is assigned a value more than once. `If the variable is an object, note that the compiler does not prohibit changes to the properties of the object.`

P.S.:
did you include the following code in your script or HTML Page ?

```
  <script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
```

Comment: The text you quoted says that you can still change the properties of a constant object. However, it is possible to mark a property of an object as constant (also see stewe's response). I am trying to get it work with the `new` operator. Also, I don't use Closure Library in my script. Closure Compiler works perfectly without it.